# copy value from a line to another line with condition using awk

Tags: awk

first thanks to all for all i learned here.

this is my input csv :

```
TYPEµREFµCOLORµ
PRODUCTµ354µblueµ
MODELµ354µµ
MODELµ354µµ
PRODUCTµ253µgreenµ
MODELµ253µµ
MODELµ253µµ
```

the separator is {FS="µ";OFS="µ"}

**what i have :**

- each PRODUCT line contain a value in COLOR column.
- each MODEL line contain a empty COLOR column.

**What i want :**

- i want to copy Color string from each PRODUCT line in color string of each MODEL line with the same REF as PRODUCT.
- (REF is the Sync KEY linking PRODUCT and MODEL.)

Result i want :

```
TYPEµREFµCOLORµ
PRODUCTµ354µblueµ
MODELµ354µblueµ
MODELµ354µblueµ
PRODUCTµ253µgreenµ
MODELµ253µgreenµ
MODELµ253µgreenµ
```

I hope i was clear....

i tried to work with if and -v a long time ....

Thanks by advance.

PéPé.

Comment: There's the awk code missing in your question you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a memory of all product

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = FS = "µ"}
   {
   if ($1 ~ /^PRODUCT/) Prod[ $2] = $3
    else if (Prod[ $2] !~ /^$/) $3 = Prod[ $2]
   print
   }' YourFile
```

assuming model are associate only to header product

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = FS = "µ"}
   {
   if ($1 ~ /^PRODUCT/){ Ref=$2; Color = $3 }
    else if ( Ref == $2 && Color !~ /^$/) $3 = Color
   print
   }' YourFile
```

Comment: The first answer is perfect with ref and using array. what i tried since 2 days :/  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F'µ' '$1 ~ /^PRODUCT/{color=$3} $1 ~ /^MODEL/{$3=color}1' OFS='µ' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `$1 ~ /^PRODUCT/` - Matching a column against `PRODUCT`.
- `color=$3` - Storing a `$3` value.
- `$1 ~ /^MODEL/`   - Matching a column against 'MODEL'.
- `$3=color` - Assigning a value to `$3`.

Comment: Perfect ! thanks ! i will play with that to verify the ref.

Comment: with the REF key : `awk -F'µ' '$1 ~ /^PRODUCT/{color=$3;ref=$2} $1 ~ /^MODEL/ && $2 ~ ref {$3=color}1' OFS='µ' file.csv` work like a charm. thanks again